# free jquery layer slider?

Tags: jquery, slider

Is there a free jquery plugin similar to

http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-the-parallax-effect-slider/922100?sso?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=kreatura

Comment: This is a question for Google, not for StackOverflow.

Comment: This question is the first result of Google search. LOL!

Comment: check out [Fraction Slider and other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715612/jquery-slider-with-text-animation-and-auto-play) ,hope helps.

Comment: Yes am working on one of slider https://github.com/nil4you/Multi-Layer-Slider. Check it's demo here http://nil4you.github.io/Multi-Layer-Slider May be you can get it 100%  working around october 2015

Comment: If you're looking a free alternative to the likes of Revolution Slider, Fraction Slider is definitely the closest option.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not that we encourage these type of questions but you might want to take a look at [WOWSLIDER](http://wowslider.com/). Google should always be your first choice.

Comment: Thanks, google directed me here:D

Comment: @PeterM in that case why didnt I get an upvote ;) ?

Comment: Sure, somehow forgotten to upvote:)