# Jquery Slider with text animation and auto play?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would want to create a slider with auto-play. To be specific that is some static images with transition and text effects. I need some text animation something like this [Text Effect](http://kreaturamedia.com/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin), Does anyone know the plugin for this so that i can implement on  a school website?

Its good if it works on IE too :)

Answer (score 5):

check this one,i like this one alot:
http://jacksbox.de/stuff/jquery-fractionslider/

Answer (score 2):

How is that?

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlideshowJmpress/index2.html

I used this slider on a page that I designed:

http://www.zinzinzibidi.com/windows_8_metro_icons_for_dock_users/

Comment: That wonderful, But i am looking for some simple image transition and text effect so that it will look good on the school website