# creating a consistent simple banner text animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hey guys i am new to javascriptand i tried creating a banner carousel animation , I.E, i have 3 banners and everytime , a slide comes in the text appears with a animation , the problem i am facing is the animations on my 3 slides ony work till the 3 slide scrolls after that , when again slide 1 slides in , the text on slide 1 is not animated and the animations just don't happen from here on .

I was inspired by banner animations from this website :

[banner text animation inspiration](http://livefitgym.com/) .

now what i have tried is the following CSS animations :

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
  0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
}

.bounceInDown {
  animation-name: bounceInDown;
}



@-webkit-keyframes bounceInRight {
  0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(3000px, 0, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
  }

  75% {
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
}

.bounceInRight {
  animation-name: bounceInRight;
}
```

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0nc4yf5w/2/) and u'll understand better .

I am really fascinated by text animations on banners , i am new to Jquery and JS in general , what will i have to do to make the animations appear on the slide , every time a new slide comes in. I have created the CSS-3 animations myself but am stuck here .

Thank you.

Alexander.

Comment: You can find answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715612/jquery-slider-with-text-animation-and-auto-play

Comment: @sym , great , but as of now i am looking at how can i do it myself rather then use a plugin . :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 items to show in a carousel method you can try this.
Make a "master" div that contain the other 3 divs.
Every div contain image background and text and use the javascript animation for text.
And slide the 3 divs like that:

```
//function that slide the divs
$(document).ready(function() {
 var counter = 1;
 $("#d1").show();
 function change(){
      //Change the 3 divs inside a master div
      if(counter == 0){
         $("#d3").hide();
         $("#d1").show();
         counter++;
     }else if(counter == 1){
         $("#d1").hide();
         $("#d2").show();
         $("#d3").hide();
         counter++;
     }else if(counter == 2){
         $("#d1").hide();
         $("#d2").hide();
         $("#d3").show();
         counter++;
     }else{
         counter = 1;
         $("#d3").hide();
         $("#d1").show();
     }

 }
//every 6 seconds
setInterval(change, 6000);
});
```

With the css set the d2 and d3 invisible so you can show and hide them with this javascript code.

Is that you are looking for?

Comment: not a big fan of hide and show , but i'll still upvote . any idea why the animations work only the 1st 3 times

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik i see your jsfiddle, i'm not sure to understand your problem.
The animations work only for the first cicle or the animation of the 3rd slide doesn't work?
As i can see on your jsfiddle the 3rd animation doesn't do nothing.
The problem is the 3rd animation bounceInRight?

Comment: everything should work fine now ! , the problem is everything until the 3rd slide works on the 2nd cycle of the slides i.e. the animations stops working !

Comment: JS fiddle is not a real browser , for some reason , even after the 1st cycle of slides , the animations work , which is not the case locally or on a real server .

Comment: you do all with css? Or you have some Jquery or javascript?

Comment: as of now , no JS or Jquery , i suspect , i will  need a Jquery solution !

Comment: But if it work for the first cycle why don't work for the others?
`transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);`
You are sure to use the correct values?
the webkit it's correct?
Maybe the error is simple, it's not a code error

Comment: there is no code error at all , also Jquery is needed because the animation will happen only once I.E when the animation class is added , for the animation to happen on every slide the class needs to be removed and added again everytime !

Comment: You can find easy some trick with JQuery or Javascript for do this.
Good luck